# Node.js connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000 DynamoDB Local Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I'm using this [NPM plugin](https://github.com/99xt/dynamodb-localhost) to handle creating a local DynamoDB local server within my Node app. For some reason sometimes it gives me the following error. Can't figure out why but it seems to always happen when running tests during a specific section of tests.

It definitely doesn't happen every time. Maybe 50% or so. Very strange.

I have read that the error means starting the DynamoDB local server failed. But I have no idea why since it doesn't give any more details.

```
DynamoDB Local failed to start with code 1
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1012:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1035:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1080:14)
  message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000',
  code: 'NetworkingError',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 8000,
  region: 'us-west-2',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  retryable: true,
  time: 2016-09-13T03:26:05.804Z }
```

Oh and here is my code to create the server.

```
    dynamodbLocal.start({port : dbport, /* Port to listen on. Default: 8000 */
         cors : '*', /* Enable CORS support (cross-origin resource sharing) for JavaScript. You must provide a comma-separated "allow" list of specific domains. The default setting for cors is an asterisk (*), which allows public access. */
         inMemory : false, /* DynamoDB; will run in memory, instead of using a database file. When you stop DynamoDB;, none of the data will be saved. Note that you cannot specify both dbPath and inMemory at once. */
         dbPath : __dirname + '/dynamodb/', /* The directory where DynamoDB will write its database file. If you do not specify this option, the file will be written to the current directory. Note that you cannot specify both dbPath and inMemory at once. For the path, current working directory is <projectroot>/node_modules/dynamodb-localhost/dynamob. For example to create <projectroot>/node_modules/dynamodb-localhost/dynamob/<mypath> you should specify '<mypath>/' with a forwardslash at the end. */
         sharedDb : false, /* DynamoDB will use a single database file, instead of using separate files for each credential and region. If you specify sharedDb, all DynamoDB clients will interact with the same set of tables regardless of their region and credential configuration. */
         delayTransientStatuses : false, /* Causes DynamoDB to introduce delays for certain operations. DynamoDB can perform some tasks almost instantaneously, such as create/update/delete operations on tables and indexes; however, the actual DynamoDB service requires more time for these tasks. Setting this parameter helps DynamoDB simulate the behavior of the Amazon DynamoDB web service more closely. (Currently, this parameter introduces delays only for global secondary indexes that are in either CREATING or DELETING status.) */
         optimizeDbBeforeStartup : true /* Optimizes the underlying database tables before starting up DynamoDB on your computer. You must also specify -dbPath when you use this parameter. */
        });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can try change the port to listen on, port 8000 is already in use so it makes this error .

Comment: @TanLe I can't find where port 8000 is already in use. I'm using Jenkins and using the build executor environment variable to detect which port to use so I can run multiple builds at once. I guess I could maybe stop the port before starting it again maybe just to be sure?

Comment: @TanLe For some reason even after doing that I'm still getting `DynamoDB Local failed to start with code 1` sometimes. The last time didn't have that ECONNREFUSED error anymore tho which is strange.